# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity with Android

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, reinstall, recreate

I'm a fairly new Android programmer, and after working through a couple of tutorials I began expanding upon the BMI Calculator tutorial I completed.  During this process, it became necessary for me to delete and re-install Eclipse.  I also had to switch workspaces.  Due to a mistake on my part, I was only able to retain the .java files for the app.  I recreated the .xml and manifest, only now I'm getting the IllegalStateException when I try to click the calculate button.  Before switching over and recreating, everything ran fine.  I'm using an emulator of the Nexus Galaxy, running 4.2.2  Here's the code:

> package com.example.bmicalculator;
>
> import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle; import
>   android.view.Menu; import android.view.View; import
>   android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.ImageView; import
>   android.widget.TextView;
>
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {  ImageDownloader
>   downloader;
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
> }
>
> public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {
>   if(view.getId() == R.id.calculateButton) {
>       EditText weightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightLabel);
>       EditText heightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightText);
>       TextView resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultLabel);
>       TextView suggestText= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.suggestedFix);
>       ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.relatedPicture);
>       float weight = Float.parseFloat(weightText.getText().toString());
>       float height = Float.parseFloat(heightText.getText().toString());
>
>       float bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);
>
>       String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);
>
>       String suggest = "We suggest " + interpretBMIInterpretation(bmiInterpretation);
>
>       resultText.setText(bmiValue + "-" + bmiInterpretation);
>       suggestText.setText(suggest);
>       setUpImage(image, bmiInterpretation);
>   }
> }
>
> private float calculateBMI(float weight, float height) {
>   return (float) (weight * 4.88 / (height * height));
> }
>
> private String interpretBMI(float bmiValue) {
>   if(bmiValue < 16) {
>       return "Severely underweight";
>   } else if (bmiValue < 18.5) {
>       return "Underweight";
>   } else if(bmiValue < 25) {
>       return "Normal";
>   }
>   else if(bmiValue < 30) {
>       return "Overweight";
>   }
>   else {
>       return "Obese";
>   }
> }
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
>     return true;
> }
>
> private String interpretBMIInterpretation(String interp) {
>   if(interp.equals("Severely underweight")) {
>       return "eating more.  You can still work out and stay thin, but you need more weight.";
>   }
>   else if(interp.equals("Underweight")) {
>       return "eating a little more, alongside working out to gain muscle weight.";
>   }
>   else if(interp.equals("Normal")) {
>       return "continuing to do whatever it is you're doing.";
>   }
>   else if(interp.equals("Overweight")) {
>       return "working out a little.  Lose a few fat poinds and put on some muscle pounds, and you'll be a healthy weight.";
>   }
>   else {
>       return "cutting back on your food intake and working out.  A little goes a long way.";
>   }
> }
>
> private void setUpImage(ImageView image, String interp) {
>   if(interp.equals("Severely underweight")) {
>       image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>       downloader = new ImageDownloader(image);
>       String url = "http://www.wendys.com/cs/Satellite?blobcol=urldata&blobheader=image%2Fpng&blobkey=id&blobtable=MungoBlobs&blobwhere=1365660287009&ssbinary=true";
>       downloader.execute(url);
>   }
>   else if(interp.equals("Underweight")) {
>       image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>       downloader = new ImageDownloader(image);
>       String url = "http://www.livestrongfitness.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/barbell.jpg";
>       downloader.execute(url);
>   }
>   else if(interp.equals("Normal")) {
>       image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>       downloader = new ImageDownloader(image);
>       String url = "http://primary3.tv/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/thumbsup.jpg";
>       downloader.execute(url);
>   }
>   else if(interp.equals("Overweight")) {
>       image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>       downloader = new ImageDownloader(image);
>       String url = "http://www.livestrongfitness.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/barbell.jpg";
>       downloader.execute(url);
>   }
>   else {
>       image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>       downloader = new ImageDownloader(image);
>       String url = "http://wisefitnesstips.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/salad-nutrients-facts.jpg";
>       downloader.execute(url);
>   }
> }
>  }
> ```

And the ImageDownload Class:

> package com.example.bmicalculator;
>
> import java.io.InputStream; import java.net.URL;
>
> import android.graphics.Bitmap; import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
>   import android.os.AsyncTask; import android.view.View; import
>   android.widget.ImageView; public class ImageDownloader extends
>   AsyncTask {
>       ImageView image;  public ImageDownloader(ImageView image) {       this.image = image;
>       }         protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
>         try {
>               Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(strings[0]).getContent());
>               return bitmap;            } catch (Exception e) {
>                 System.out.println("Error: " + e);
>                 return null;            }
>       }
>
> ```
> protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
>
> }
>
> protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
>   image.setImageBitmap(result);
>   image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
> } }
> ```

And the LogCat:

> 05-23 14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-23 14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the
>   activity 05-23 14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):  at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599) 05-23 14:45:52.447:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1083):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 05-23 14:45:52.447:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1083):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 05-23
>   14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 05-23
>   14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 05-23
>   14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 05-23 14:45:52.447:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1083):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 05-23
>   14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-23
>   14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 05-23 14:45:52.447:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1083):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   05-23 14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 05-23
>   14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-23 14:45:52.447:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1083): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 05-23 14:45:52.447:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1083):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-23
>   14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 05-23 14:45:52.447:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1083):   at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594) 05-23 14:45:52.447:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1083):   ... 11 more 05-23 14:45:52.447:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1083): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
>   05-23 14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):   at
>   com.example.bmicalculator.MainActivity.calculateClickHandler(MainActivity.java:23)
>   05-23 14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083):   ... 14 more 05-23
>   14:47:48.527: D/dalvikvm(1158): GC_CONCURRENT freed 55K, 7% free
>   2770K/2948K, paused 6ms+14ms, total 96ms 05-23 14:47:48.877:
>   D/gralloc_goldfish(1158): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>   05-23 14:47:53.837: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1158): KeyEvent:
>   ACTION_UP but key was not down. 05-23 14:47:53.837:
>   D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1158):   in
>   android.widget.EditText{40d2d8e8 VFED..CL .F....I. 32,209-452,288
>
> ## 7f080003 app:id/heightText} 05-23 14:47:53.837: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1158):   0: sent at 922301000000,
>
> KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15,
>   metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=922301,
>   downTime=922168, deviceId=0, source=0x101 } 05-23 14:47:55.097:
>   D/AndroidRuntime(1158): Shutting down VM 05-23 14:47:55.097:
>   W/dalvikvm(1158): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x40a71930) 05-23 14:47:55.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 05-23 14:47:55.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the
>   activity 05-23 14:47:55.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):  at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599) 05-23 14:47:55.187:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1158):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 05-23 14:47:55.187:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1158):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 05-23
>   14:47:55.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 05-23
>   14:47:55.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 05-23
>   14:47:55.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 05-23 14:47:55.187:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1158):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 05-23
>   14:47:55.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-23
>   14:47:55.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 05-23 14:47:55.187:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1158):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   05-23 14:47:55.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 05-23
>   14:47:55.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-23 14:47:55.187:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1158): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 05-23 14:47:55.187:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1158):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-23
>   14:47:55.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 05-23 14:47:55.187:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1158):   at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594) 05-23 14:47:55.187:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1158):   ... 11 more 05-23 14:47:55.187:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1158): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
>   05-23 14:47:55.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):   at
>   com.example.bmicalculator.MainActivity.calculateClickHandler(MainActivity.java:23)
>   05-23 14:47:55.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):   ... 14 more 05-23
>   14:47:57.797: I/Process(1158): Sending signal. PID: 1158 SIG: 9

I've made sure that all ids used for reference are correct.  The app appears to have been built just like it was before I moved everything over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText 05-23 14:45:52.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1083): at 

 EditText weightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightLabel);
 EditText heightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightText);
```

one from `weightText` and `heightText` is a `TextView`.

Comment: That was it...I accidentally switched which id was weightLabel and weightText in the XML file.  Thank you!